# Finding all parents in a single query with parent and child ranges

Tags: sql, db2, parent-child

I have the following table in DB2 with parent and child ranges. Each row contains the parent and the corresponding minimum and maximum value that its children can have:

```
    parent         child_min   child_max
    ------         ---------   ----------
      1              100           300
      2              500           899
     ...
     ...
```

Now, I am trying to find the parents of a set of children in a single query.

Example: I have child ids:

```
    101, 102, 105, 208, 506.
```

Now the query should return their respective parents

```
    1,1,1,1,2.
```

I did it by CTE .

```
    WITH temp(id) AS (VALUES
    101,102,105,208,506)
    SELECT parent FROM table,temp 
    WHERE child_min < = temp.id
    AND child_max >= temp.id
```

But is there another way to do it without CTE in a single query ?

Comment: Your query *is* a single query.  It happens to use a CTE, but that is very reasonable.

Comment: Agreed. A Common Table Expression (CTE) is not a "temp table".

Comment: Um, I have a problem with your schema design: Your child ranges appear to be designating the minimum/maximum **id** the child can have, which is going to have terrible effects on the design (for one thing, no auto-gen id on that table).  _Usually_, parent/child relationships are done by storing a self-reference (ie, each child stores its parent).  Also, your upper-bound is inclusive, which irks me (but isn't too big an issue)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple `JOIN`. Considering the following data (I added an extra row):

```
create table parent_children (
  parent int,
  child_min int,
  child_max int
);

insert into parent_children (parent, child_min, child_max) values (1, 100, 300);
insert into parent_children (parent, child_min, child_max) values (2, 500, 899);
```

The query would be:

```
with children (id) as (values 101, 102, 105, 208, 506, 1000)
select c.id, p.parent
  from children c
  left join parent_children p on c.id between p.child_min and p.child_max;
```

Result:

```
ID          PARENT       
----------  -------
101         1            
102         1            
105         1            
208         1            
506         2            
1000        <null>
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid CTE. Can it be done without CTE?

Comment: Yes, the CTE is for demo purposes only. If you have the child IDs in another table, you can use that one instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you prefer this?

```
SELECT parent
FROM table
, TABLE(VALUES  101,102,105,208,506) AS t(id) 
WHERE child_min <= t.id
AND child_max >= t.id;
```